# SQL join on enum column returns all possible values

Tags: sql, join, enums

I have a SQL query that selects an enum column and performs a join. Here are the DB tables involved and relevant data:

OFFER TABLE

```
-- 
-- Table structure for table `offer`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `offer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `details` text NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  `maxAmount` decimal(11,0) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dateExpires` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `active` enum('YES','NO') NOT NULL,
  `featured` enum('YES','NO') NOT NULL default 'NO',
  `adType` enum('OFFER','URL') NOT NULL default 'OFFER',
  `URL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `companyID` (`companyID`),
  KEY `categoryID` (`categoryID`),
  KEY `zip` (`zip`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=66 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=66 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `offer`
-- 

INSERT INTO `offer` (`id`, `companyID`, `categoryID`, `dateAdded`, `details`, `amount`, `maxAmount`, `dateExpires`, `active`, `featured`, `adType`, `URL`, `address1`, `address2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`) VALUES 
(24, 10, 6, '2011-05-19 14:55:54', 'Computer Software & Books', 25, 0, 0, 'NO', 'NO', 'OFFER', '', '912 N. Avenue 57', '', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', '90043')
```

PAYMENTS TABLE

```
-- 
-- Table structure for table `payments`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `offerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `validationNumber` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('NEW','USED') NOT NULL default 'NEW',
  `dateRedeemed` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `validationNumber` (`validationNumber`),
  KEY `offerID` (`offerID`),
  KEY `memberID` (`memberID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=33 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=33 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `payments`
-- 

INSERT INTO `payments` (`id`, `date`, `offerID`, `amount`, `memberID`, `validationNumber`, `status`, `dateRedeemed`) VALUES
(1, '2011-03-28 16:33:24', 24, 11.00, 8, '1A2B3-1', 'NEW', '2011-07-18 15:00:41'),
(2, '2011-04-12 12:47:58', 16, 81.10, 8, '2C3D4-2', 'NEW', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(3, '2011-05-19 19:50:58', 24, 22.15, 14, 'ABCDE-3', 'USED', '2011-07-18 15:03:00'),
(4, '2011-05-19 19:50:58', 24, 44.30, 5, 'FGHIJK-4', 'USED', '2011-07-18 15:03:45');
```

TRANSACTIONS TABLE

```
-- 
-- Table structure for table `transactions`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `offerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('CREDIT','DEBIT') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `companyID` (`companyID`,`offerID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=38 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `transactions`
-- 

INSERT INTO `transactions` (`id`, `companyID`, `offerID`, `date`, `amount`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 10, 24, '2011-05-20 11:25:35', 11.00, 'CREDIT'),
(2, 10, 24, '2011-05-20 11:25:35', 22.15, 'CREDIT'),
(3, 10, 24, '2011-05-20 11:26:11', 44.30, 'CREDIT'),
(4, 10, 0, '2011-05-20 14:55:13', -3.50, 'DEBIT'),
(5, 10, 0, '2011-05-20 14:59:50', -5.00, 'DEBIT'),
(6, 10, 0, '2011-05-20 15:45:29', -4.50, 'DEBIT'),
(36, 10, 0, '2011-07-08 15:03:06', -10.00, 'DEBIT'),
(37, 10, 0, '2011-07-08 15:03:19', -2.45, 'DEBIT');
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, o.amount AS discount, p.status FROM transactions t 
            LEFT JOIN offer o ON o.id = t.offerID 
            LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.offerId = t.offerID
            WHERE t.companyID = '10' ORDER BY date ASC
```

Finally, here's the result set:

```
id  companyID   offerID     date    amount  type    discount    status
1   10  24  2011-05-20 11:25:35     11.00   CREDIT  25  NEW
1   10  24  2011-05-20 11:25:35     11.00   CREDIT  25  USED
2   10  24  2011-05-20 11:25:35     22.15   CREDIT  25  NEW
2   10  24  2011-05-20 11:25:35     22.15   CREDIT  25  USED
3   10  24  2011-05-20 11:26:11     44.30   CREDIT  25  USED
3   10  24  2011-05-20 11:26:11     44.30   CREDIT  25  NEW
4   10  0   2011-05-20 14:55:13     -3.50   DEBIT   NULL    NULL
5   10  0   2011-05-20 14:59:50     -5.00   DEBIT   NULL    NULL
6   10  0   2011-05-20 15:45:29     -4.50   DEBIT   NULL    NULL
36  10  0   2011-07-08 15:03:06     -10.00  DEBIT   NULL    NULL
37  10  0   2011-07-08 15:03:19     -2.45   DEBIT   NULL    NULL
```

The problem is that the CREDIT results appear twice with both NEW and USED enum values. I only want the enum value that the payments row is set to. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand why this query is not working, and how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

@michael, @chopikadze:

I have added memberID to the transactions table.
I have revised my query thus:

```
SELECT t. * , o.amount AS discount, p.status
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN offer o ON o.id = t.offerID
LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.offerId = t.offerID
LEFT JOIN members m ON m.id = t.memberID
WHERE t.companyID = '10'
ORDER BY date ASC
```

And this is my new result set:

```
id  companyID   offerID     memberID    date    amount  type    discount    status
1   10  24  8   2011-05-20 11:25:35     11.00   CREDIT  25  NEW
1   10  24  8   2011-05-20 11:25:35     11.00   CREDIT  25  USED
1   10  24  8   2011-05-20 11:25:35     11.00   CREDIT  25  USED
2   10  24  14  2011-05-20 11:25:35     22.15   CREDIT  25  NEW
2   10  24  14  2011-05-20 11:25:35     22.15   CREDIT  25  USED
2   10  24  14  2011-05-20 11:25:35     22.15   CREDIT  25  USED
3   10  24  5   2011-05-20 11:26:11     44.30   CREDIT  25  NEW
3   10  24  5   2011-05-20 11:26:11     44.30   CREDIT  25  USED
3   10  24  5   2011-05-20 11:26:11     44.30   CREDIT  25  USED
4   10  0   0   2011-05-20 14:55:13     -3.50   DEBIT   NULL    NULL
5   10  0   0   2011-05-20 14:59:50     -5.00   DEBIT   NULL    NULL
6   10  0   0   2011-05-20 15:45:29     -4.50   DEBIT   NULL    NULL
36  10  0   0   2011-07-08 15:03:06     -10.00  DEBIT   NULL    NULL
37  10  0   0   2011-07-08 15:03:19     -2.45   DEBIT   NULL    NULL
```

It seems that adding memberID has resulted in more duplicate results. What did I do wrong? Please correct me on this one guys. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have two records in the `payments` table for a given offer? I could understand storing history, but you also seem to have `redeemedDate` which is weird if `NEW` records will never use it. I'd probably just change the `payments` record to `USED` when it's used instead of inserting a second record

Comment: @Michael, I think the result set has confused you. There is only one payments record for each offer. Initially, that record has a status of NEW. Once the payment has been redeemed, the status changes to USED. But in the result set, BOTH status values appear which is not what I want. I want the current status of the payments record. I hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: how is a payment mapped to a transaction? You need to specify that in your join condition--it's probably more than just offerid

Comment: Michael is right. Your joins doubles your records, because there is not unique correspondences between transactions and payments table. Look yourself: you have 3 transactions with OfferID = 24, which have all the fields the same, only date and amount are different. Also you has 3 payments with OfferID = 24, with different date, amount, memberID, validationNumber and status. When you join this tables just on OfferID, you actually have 9 (!) = 3*3, but your "distinct" keeps only 6 rows. "Distinct" keyword usually used not in this situation.

Comment: Maybe, you should add memberID field to transaction table? And join transactions and payments not only on OfferID, but on memberID too. And you should remove "distinct" from your query - as I said, it is usually used for another case.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is usually your first clue that something is wrong with a query - why are you getting multiple results?

Comment: @chopikadze: I have taken your advice, but somehow I must have implemented it incorrectly, because there are now more duplicate results. Please see my edits. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t. * , o.amount AS discount, p.status
FROM transactions t
    LEFT JOIN offer o ON o.id = t.offerID
    LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.offerId = t.offerID and p.memberID = t.memberID
WHERE t.companyID = '10'
ORDER BY date ASC
```

As I said, you should not only

> add memberID field to transaction table

but also

> join transactions and payments not only on OfferID, but on memberID too

Comment: or just join on payments amount and transaction amount, if it is possible (just noticed that they are equal), but it depends on logical rules in db